# convert Datatable to XML

Tags: c#, xml, dataset

I have a `dataset` containing lot of `datatables`. I want to convert each `datatable` to One `XML`. But the column names of `datatables` are not in proper manner.

Column name of `datatable` is like, `flt_no`. But I need to change this to like XML column name `FlightNumber`.

I tried with `datatable.WriteXML` and `dataset.WriteXML` method to achieve this.

Is there any other way?

Comment: One option is `String.Replace` (depends on possible content of your xml) i.e. `xml = xml.Replace("fit_no", "FlightNumber")`

Comment: Ok but lot of columns are there like Fltdtls to FlightDetails, etc...I should say to my boss that "It is not possible"

Comment: Change the columns name first.

Comment: There are 15 datatables in that dataset...And, each datatable can have 20-25 columns. If i try to change the name of each column, it will take 2 days. :(

Comment: @user1089345 So before filling datatables use SQL alias syntax for tables.

Comment: tell your boss that its possible. But time consuming. And whoever wrote this database names should fix it. There is no fast way to complete this task.